# Using a string method inside a template literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, template-literals

I have to format a date, but said date is inside a template literal, I cannot create a variable outside, and format it before, I think, since it is inside of a map function:

```
$.getJSON(  base_url + '/xxx/wp-json/wp/v2/news?housing_type' + id, posts => { 
    $('.page__content__news__inner-wrap').html(`
        ${posts.map( item =>
            `<div class="news__item"><a href="${item.news_url}" class="news__item__link" target="_blank"><p class="news__item__date">${item.date}</p><h3 class="news__item__title">${item.title.rendered}&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3></a></div>`)}
    `);
});
```

What I need to do is to display this part:

```
${item.date}
```

With a specific format, something like this (which of course doesn't work):

```
${item.date}.format("mmmm d, yyyy")
```

Is there a way to add ${item.date} to a variable in this scenario so I can format it?

Comment: Everything inside the `${}` can be javascript.  So long as it results in a value returned.  Given that, `format()` can be put inside it as well. For instance: `\`Your name is ${'me'.toUpperCase()}\`` is perfectly valid.

Comment: I have tried ${item.date.format("mmmm d, yyyy")} but it doesn't work, how could I do it?

Comment: Are you sure that `item.date` is a Date object?

Comment: No, it's a simple string. it's JSON, look at the full function above...So I guess I should parse it first.

Comment: Well, both `String.prototype.format` and `Date.prototype.format` do not exist.  So it looks like you're using the wrong method either way.

Comment: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: You may want to consider not nesting string templates like that; it can make the code hard to read. Note that calling `html()` with an array of strings automatically joins them.